# Loading script onto page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am having some trouble loading some javascript onto a page. It works when I embed the script directly into the page, but when I use ajax/jquery/getScript, it doesn't load. I think it might have something to do with async/sync or maybe some kind of cross domain restrictions.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>

$.ajax({
    url: 'http://mobile.adnxs.com/ttj?id=1573223',
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: "script",
    success: function () {
        // script is loaded
    },
    error: function () {
        // handle errors
    }
});

</script>
```

Comment: Cross-domain could very well have something to do with it. By default, AJAX going across domains is blocked (but not a direct <script> inclusion.) In either Google Chrome or Firefox, do you see any warnings to do with cross-site requests?

Comment: check this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506208/jquery-ajax-cross-domain

Comment: Could you use: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/ ?

Comment: I'm not receiving any warnings, and I'm able to see the script load on the page. It just does nothing.

Comment: I've tried getScript, but it's the same result.

Comment: After looking at this again, I realized that the script source link is likely a PHP file that builds a the lines of JS. Any thoughts on how I could use JS to load the PHP so that it runs similarly to direct <script> inclusion, or is this not possible?

Answer (score 0):

You could inject the script tag dynamically:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var scriptTag = document.createElement('script');
    scriptTag.src = 'http://mobile.adnxs.com/ttj?id=1573223';
    scriptTag.onload = function() { /* script is loaded */ };
    scriptTag.onerror = function() { /* danger zone! * };
    $('head').append(scriptTag);
});
```

This works cross-domain, too.

Comment: Thanks Evan, I tried this; the script loads, but I'm not getting any output on the page.

Comment: @NicholasMitchell Is it supposed to give an output?

Comment: Evan, yes there should be an output on the page. I've determined that the link is actually to php or something server side which echoes the javascript. So far, I've only been able to get an output by using document.write(). This is not an ideal solution, though.